How to send pdf email attachment by an Event trigger in Google Apps Script?
Overview: I have implemented a Google Forms that tracks a user's responses and the responses are stored in an Google Sheets spreadsheet.
I have also implemented a function in Apps script, with the following goals:

After Google Forms submission, an Event trigger is initiated to convert the user results to a PDF
The PDF file (Google Docs with variables that align to the Google Sheets columns) is sent to a Temp Folder in Google Drive
Email the user their responses that includes a PDF attachment

Current issue: The user responses are successfully sent to the Google Sheets as anticipated, and their responses are converted to a Pdf file on my Google Drive, but the emails are not being sent.
function afterFormSubmit(e) {

    const info = e.namedValues;
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);

    sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'][0],pdfFile);
  
}

function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email,"Here is Your PDF","Your PDF is Attached.",{
    attachments: [pdfFile],
    name: 'Sent From Example'   

  });

}


function createPDF(info,filename){


const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iCVsXmeSMHOpISQslJhX7r842aSHrqos");
const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iCVsXmeSMHOpISQslJhX7r842aSHrqos");
const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("18zVh4aL2Dbt76l6XqwIh2KHeJf6JkY-lMU63MRVOQUM");

const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body = openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{date}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Email_Address}", info['Email Address'][0]);
body.replaceText("{selected_responses}", info['Which of these Positive Attitudes do you struggle with?'][0]);

body.replaceText("{Post-Att-01}", info['Choose a positive attitude that you find difficult to maintain.'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Happens-When-01}", info['IT HAPPENS WHEN'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Triggered-By-01}", info['TRIGGERED BY'][0]);
body.replaceText("{RC-Thought #1-01}", info['Rational Counter-Thought #1'][0]);
body.replaceText("{RC-Thought #2-01}", info['Rational Counter-Thought #2'][0]);
body.replaceText("{RC-Thought #3-01}", info['Rational Counter-Thought #3'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Account-Partner-01}", info['Accountability Partner'][0]);
body.replaceText("{Post-Att-02}", info['Select another positive attitude that you find difficult to maintain.'][0]);



openDoc.saveAndClose();


const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("Worksheet Summary");
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

}

Dummy Spreadsheet

Modification points:

In your function createPDF, no value is returned. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.
Also, in the current stage, removeFile has been deprecated. Ref At tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);, you might want to remove newTempFile?

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
In this modification, the function createPDF is modified.
From:
const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("Worksheet Summary");
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

}

To:
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("Worksheet Summary");
  newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
  return blobPDF; // or return pdfFile;
}

The whole modified function is as follows. By the way, it seems that filename is not used.
function createPDF(info, filename) {
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iCVsXmeSMHOpISQslJhX7r842aSHrqos");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1iCVsXmeSMHOpISQslJhX7r842aSHrqos");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("18zVh4aL2Dbt76l6XqwIh2KHeJf6JkY-lMU63MRVOQUM");
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{date}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Email_Address}", info['Email Address'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{selected_responses}", info['Which of these Positive Attitudes do you struggle with?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Post-Att-01}", info['Choose a positive attitude that you find difficult to maintain.'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Happens-When-01}", info['IT HAPPENS WHEN'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Triggered-By-01}", info['TRIGGERED BY'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{RC-Thought #1-01}", info['Rational Counter-Thought #1'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{RC-Thought #2-01}", info['Rational Counter-Thought #2'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{RC-Thought #3-01}", info['Rational Counter-Thought #3'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Account-Partner-01}", info['Accountability Partner'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Post-Att-02}", info['Select another positive attitude that you find difficult to maintain.'][0]);
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName("Worksheet Summary");
  newTempFile.setTrashed(true);
  return blobPDF; // or return pdfFile;
}


By this modification, when the form is submitted, when the function afterFormSubmit(e) of the container-bound script in Google Spreadsheet is installed as the OnSubmit trigger, the function is automatically run and the email is sent with the attachment file.

Note:

If you want to permanently delete the file newTempFile, you can also use Drive.Files.remove(newTempFile.getId()) instead of newTempFile.setTrashed(true). But, at that time, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.


Thanks for in-depth response and noting the variables that I'm mistakenly not using. This is now functioning as anticipated. Thanks

@Jarvis Davis Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glas your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
